# Conditional Formatting in VBA, based on functions

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have some (semi) complex conditional formatting to do in Excel.  I can get it working no problem using the menu, but I want to do it programmatically because I want it applied across multiple sheets (copy, paste as format does not work).

I tried recording a macro while I set up the CF to get the code, but it doesn't record that type of entry.

Here are the rules I'm applying, currently to the range: =$1:$65536

```
=OR(COLUMN()=1,COLUMN()=2,ISBLANK($B1))
=AND(LEFT($A1,6)="Base (",A1>100)
=AND(LEFT($A1,6)="Base (",A1>=75,A1<=100)
=AND(LEFT($A1,6)="Base (",A1>=50,A1<75)
=AND(LEFT($A1,6)="Base (",A1<50)
=$B1-9.999  (current cell is less than this value)
```

Like I said, I can copy this manually by copying a whole column from one sheet to the next, but I can't copy it across all sheets, and I'd like to find a way to do it as a Macro so it can easily be applied to new workbooks (which tend to have 10-15 sheets).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sub DoCFRules()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells

    rng.Parent.Activate
    rng.Cells(1).Select 'Important!

    ApplyCF rng, "=OR(COLUMN()=1,COLUMN()=2,ISBLANK($B1))", RGB(0, 255, 0)
    ApplyCF rng, "=AND(LEFT(A1,6)=""Base ("",A1>100)", RGB(255, 0, 0)
    'etc...

End Sub

Sub ApplyCF(rng As Range, sFormula As String, clr As Long)
    With rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=sFormula)
        .Interior.Color = clr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: +1  Also, in case you might run this macro more than once on the same sheet, you might consider first removing any existing conditional formatting.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is fantastic.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, hopefully you get this.  One other question, how would it work for the last rule, where I'm comparing the current cell to a value in a fixed column?  Do I need to do anything special to tell it to Stop If True?

Comment: @JFC- if a different cell is active then the formulas do not come out as expected: try it out - it's very confusing!

Comment: @McB - you can add another (optional?) parameter to the ApplyCF method which can take a Boolean indicating "stop if true", then add a line below the color line to set that value.