# Excel changes conditional formatting formula

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I have a table containing a lot of cells representing a time line (one cell per minute, very small width) and I want to visualize operations, containing of three phases, in this table. (There can be several operations in one line, representing one operating room)

For example, if the preparation starts at 10:00 and the real operation starts at 10:23, all 23 cells between those times should get red, and the next 55, representing the actual operation between 10:23 and 11:18, should be green, and so on, like this:

```
   17    18      19    20    21      22     23     00     01      02      03     04
   |      |      |      |     |      |      |      |      |       |       |      |
OR1______________++++=================****______________++=========***____________
OR2______________________+++++======================*****_________________________
```

Each of the cells is formatted if a time value for it (taken from an extra row) is between two of the start/end values, with special cases for numbers around midnight.

To automate this (there are a lot of operations) I wrote a macro which runs through the table of the times (four time columns for the starts and endings of the three phases and one representing the operation room) and assigns each column in the big table (with the colored cells) three conditional formats, which should work correctly (I checked them manually):

```
T = time.Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
Z1 = t1.Address
Z2 = t2.Address
Z3 = t3.Address
Z4 = t4.Address

fnc1 = "=OR(AND(" & Z1 & "<=" & T & ";" & T & "<" & Z2 & ");AND(" & Z2 & "<" & Z1 & ";" & Z1 & "<=" & T & ");AND(" & T & "<" & Z2 & ";" & Z2 & "<" & Z1 & "))"
fnc2 = "=OR(AND(" & Z2 & "<=" & T & ";" & T & "<" & Z3 & ");AND(" & Z3 & "<" & Z2 & ";" & Z2 & "<=" & T & ");AND(" & T & "<" & Z3 & ";" & Z3 & "<" & Z2 & "))"
fnc3 = "=OR(AND(" & Z3 & "<=" & T & ";" & T & "<" & Z4 & ");AND(" & Z4 & "<" & Z3 & ";" & Z3 & "<=" & T & ");AND(" & T & "<" & Z4 & ";" & Z4 & "<" & Z3 & "))"

Dim currentLine As Range
Set currentLine = Range(Cells(dline, data.Column), Cells(dline, data.Column).Offset(0, width))

Set frmt1 = currentLine.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1:=fnc1)
Set frmt2 = currentLine.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1:=fnc2)
Set frmt3 = currentLine.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1:=fnc3)

frmt1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
frmt2.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
frmt3.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
```

't1' .. 't4' are the cells of the table with start/end times, 'time' is the extra row with the literal time for each column in the visualization table (10:01, 10:02,..., with the same width as 'data'), 'data' is the visualization table and 'dline' is the number of the currently formatted row, calculated depending on the operation room. 'width' is now usually 300, but in general 60 * the hours shown (so just the number of minutes of that time).

This whole thing works without errors, and it produces the right formatting strings (I checked fnc1..fnc3 in debugging mode). They look like this, which they should do:

```
=OR(AND($KR$10<=C$13;C$13<$KS$10);AND($KS$10<$KR$10;$KR$10<=C$13);AND(C$13<$KS$10;$KS$10<$KR$10))
```

C13 is the first cell of time, and KR10 and KS10 are 't1' and 't2' for this operation (the start of preparation, and the start of actual operating/end of preparation).

But: as soon as the format strings are saved to excel (macro finished), they are not the same anymore. Usually something like

```
=OR(AND($KR$10<=XCS$13;XCS$13<$KS$10);AND($KS$10<$KR$10;$KR$10<=XCS$13);AND(XCS$13<$KS$10;$KS$10<$KR$10))
```

comes out - the value of the 'time' cell, which is the only relative one, changes to strange, high values ('XCS', 'WTC', 'XBR'...). If I make the row relative, too, it also canges (I got numbers like 163552 with that).

This seems to be independent of the macro, since I first tried the whole thing in IronPython, which worked the same way (I actually translated the macro from that code) and produced the same error.

I even sometimes got the same kind of error when I was assigning the formula by hand for testing, so I strongly suspect Excel of being the real error...

Now, since I couldn't find anyhing about a similar error, could that have to to with memory? Like, too many cells? Or something specific to my computer/installation/code/...?

I use Excel 2007. The cells of the 'data' table are not specially formatted, the times are all hh:mm:ss.

I hope I made it clear enough how the whole stuff works; otherwise, just ask for more code or whatever information  is needed. Thanks for any hints, I've been stuck at this for for a week now and I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: What is the value of width here? Offset(0, width).  It's still early in the morning but I am thinking that having ColumnAbsolute:=False for T might produce unexpected results when you put the formula into a cell compared to when you check the formula in the debugger as you mentioned.

Comment: + 1 for taking time to explain your question :)

Comment: You may find you get different/strange results when applying conditional formatting using VBA, depending on the location of the active cell at the time: try selecting the first cell in the range you're applying the cf to, before you add the conditions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316662/conditional-formatting-in-vba-based-on-functions/8318151#8318151

Comment: @SiddharthRout Well, it was friday afternoon and there wasn't anything more to do at work...

Comment: @deusxmach1na It needs to be `False`, since otherwise it always compares the time to the very first minute of `time`. But anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks a lot for the decisive hint! I'll upvote as soon as I get the provilege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Credit goes to Tim Williams)

The issue seems to have to do something with the location of the active cell, changing during the process. The following code works and will be used (I also corrected another error I couldn't see before):

```
T = time.Address(True, False)
' here I initially forgot to update the row (not related to problem)
Z1 = Cells(tline, t1.Column).Address
Z2 = Cells(tline, t2.Column).Address
Z3 = Cells(tline, t3.Column).Address
Z4 = Cells(tline, t4.Column).Address

fnc1 = "=OR(AND(" & Z1 & "<=" & T & ";" & T & "<" & Z2 & ");AND(" & Z2 & "<" & Z1 & ";" & Z1 & "<=" & T & ");AND(" & T & "<" & Z2 & ";" & Z2 & "<" & Z1 & "))"
fnc2 = "=OR(AND(" & Z2 & "<=" & T & ";" & T & "<" & Z3 & ");AND(" & Z3 & "<" & Z2 & ";" & Z2 & "<=" & T & ");AND(" & T & "<" & Z3 & ";" & Z3 & "<" & Z2 & "))"
fnc3 = "=OR(AND(" & Z3 & "<=" & T & ";" & T & "<" & Z4 & ");AND(" & Z4 & "<" & Z3 & ";" & Z3 & "<=" & T & ");AND(" & T & "<" & Z4 & ";" & Z4 & "<" & Z3 & "))"

Dim currentLine As Range
Set currentLine = Range(Cells(dline, data.Column), Cells(dline, data.Column).Offset(0, width))
currentLine.Select ' <- neccessary change solving the problem

Set frmt1 = currentLine.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1:=fnc1)
Set frmt2 = currentLine.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1:=fnc2)
Set frmt3 = currentLine.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1:=fnc3)

frmt1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
frmt2.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
frmt3.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
```